# Delayed expansion with string manipulation and variable

Tags: batch-file

The following command in a batch file returns the error

> "`1!==1` was unexpected at this time"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num1=0
set/p "pass=>"
:start
set/a num1=%num1%+1
set/a num2=%num1%-1
if !pass:~%num2%,1!==1 set pass%num1%=1& goto start
```

The last line repeats once for every one digit number, the `==1` being replaced.

Comment: The pass variable is not defined yet so the IF command fails.

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to add that to the description. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't say what you are entering as "pass", we're guessing.

Your `if` command should be

```
if "!pass:~%num2%,1!"=="1" set pass%num1%=1& goto start
```

which ensures that both sides of the operator `==` sontain non-empty strings.

That won't help your logic flaws, but it will cure the error report. You don't say clearly what you are trying to achieve, so beyond that...who knows?

Comment: I'm making a low-level text encryptor. It also includes letters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a temporary variable for your if command, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set num1=0
set/p "pass=>"
:start
set/a num1=%num1%+1
set/a num2=%num1%-1
set "temppass=!pass:~%num2%,1!"
if [%temppass%]==[1] echo set pass%num1%=1& goto start
pause
```

The pause and the echo in the if are for debug-purposes and should probably be removed